# Polymer JS allowing one variable to be incorrect ("0")

Tags: javascript

I am writing a code in polymer js and i need help with one thing.
i am using grep to find lets say kit of elements , that few elements should be equal to elements that i am searching for.
for example i have a table that looks like this:

```
ID     NAME     SECOND     THIRD     FOURTH  
1      5        4          6         0  
2      1        2          6         9    
3      5        4          0         1
```

and search elements are NAME=5 SECOND=4 THIRD=6 FOURTH=1

so in this case grep should search for exact match, if there is no match then grep should search a match allowing one search element to be 0, so it should search with these elements:

```
NAME=0 SECOND=4 THIRD=6 FOURTH=1  
NAME=5 SECOND=0 THIRD=6 FOURTH=1  
NAME=5 SECOND=4 THIRD=0 FOURTH=1  
NAME=5 SECOND=4 THIRD=6 FOURTH=0
```

as a result grep should catch element kits with id 1 and 3.

So the big questiong is: how to allow each element in grep to be 0, and for example if there are no results with one variable equal to 0 , then it should allow to make two variables equal to 0.

Really sorry for my bad interpretation, i would be really gratefull if anyone would help me. if you have any questions how i can ease understanding of the task, just write a comment. Thank you.

```
var NAME = 5;
var SECOND = 4;
var THIRD = 6;
var FOURTH = 1;  

found_kits = $.grep(this.kit, function(e) {
   return e.NAME == NAME && el.SECOND == SECOND && el.THIRD == THIRD && el.FOURTH == FOURTH;
});
```

Comment: Where's the code? is this a question about using grep or javascript?

Comment: its the question about the iteration: i would need to allow iteration thru those search element alowing each one to be a 0. and then to search with each combination by grep. I can try to put code that i have now here.

Comment: Does it work if you change the `==` to `===` everywhere in your return statement? You may be getting bitten by javascript's typecasting.

Comment: it wont help as i need to change each by each variable value to 0. i think i would help me if i would put those variables into array [5,4,6,1] and then iterate with function thrue each variable making 4 possible new arrays [0,4,6,1][5,0,6,1][5,4,0,1][5,4,6,0], but how i can mane a function that will make all possible arrays with two zero's?